# Angular 6.1.1 @input doesn´t work

Tags: angular

Im new to angular, Im trying to pass data from the parent component to a child compoment, currently I am folowing a tutorial step by step, the tutorial is aprox 1 year old, so I wonder if changes in angular don´t let me get this done.

Module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppFather } from './app.father';
import { AppSon } from './app.son';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppFather, AppSon
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppFather, AppSon]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.father.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-father',
  templateUrl: './app.father.html',
})
export class AppFather {
  firstMessage = {
       number: 1,
       message: 'Hi, how are you'             
  };
}
```

app.son.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-son',
    templateUrl: './app.son.html',
})
export class AppSon {
    @Input() message;
}
```

app.father.html

```
<h1>Father</h1>
<app-son [message]="firstMessage"></app-son>
```

app.son.html

```
<h3>{{message.message}}</h3>
<h3>{{message.number}}</h3>
```

Comment: It's just `{{message}}` not `{{message.message}}`

Comment: what's the observed behavior? is there an error message? why are you bootstrapping the components? what does app.component.html look like?

Comment: @DiegoCardozo looks like you are incorrect and `{{message.message}}` is appropriate. `message` is an object with a property named `message`. One *likely* problem I see is in the `bootstrap: [AppFather, AppSon]`. It should probably just be `bootstrap: [AppFather]`

Comment: Thanks bryan6 and John that was it, why bootstraping AppSon results in not showing the objects properties?

Comment: @John you are right, I didn't paid attention now that I read the whole question again. Thanks for the catch sir.

Comment: @ThisNameWasTaken You're only suppose to bootstrap the root component. I've never seen an app, or tutorial, or Angular example, where you bootstrapped two components. I'm not actually familiar enough with the bootstrapping process to tell you why though (other than to say, "thats just the way it works"). In your app, the root component is `AppFather`. Obviously there are cases when it does make sense to bootstrap multiple components though, otherwise the `bootstrap` property wouldn't take an array. [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#the-bootstrap-array) has some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely problem I see is in the `bootstrap: [AppFather, AppSon]`. It should probably just be `bootstrap: [AppFather]`.